# laravel, displaying data on a dropdown from another table but saving in current table

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables, a `user` table and a `working_hours` table. on the Add screen for `working_hours` I want a drop down to allow a user to pick an ID from the `users` table and when the submit button is pressed, it will store in my `working_hours` table under the `worker_id` column.

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $energy = new Work;
        $energy->staff_id = $request->input('staff_id');  
        $energy->work_time = $request->input('work_time');
        $energy->save();
        return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
```

Model:

```
class Work extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'work_log';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['date'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

dropdown list:

```
<div>
<label>Select Staff</label>
<select name="staff_id" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I am very new to Laravel so I dont know what to put in that drop down.

Doe anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller with which you can obtain the list of users first. Create a controller called `StaffController` with an `index` method and load the users you need on the front-end.

If you're using blade templates you can then use a foreach;

```html
    <div>
    <label>Select Staff</label>
    <select name="staff_id" >
    @foreach($staff as $staff_mebers)
        <option value="{{ $staff->id }}">{{ $staff->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: `class StaffController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $energy = Staff::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.vmaintenance')->with('energy', $energy);
    }
  
}`